# shade in table not showing in actual email

Tags: html

i am using the following format as a template for sending emails with tables.
the format is suppose to change the shading between the table lines.

when the email is sent to Outlock or Gmail the shading switch does not show.  but when extracting the emails HTML to an online HTML editor the switch is shown.

Please assist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#outlook a {
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
    width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
ol li, ol li p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.pe-ol {
    margin-left:20px !important;
}
img {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#backgroundTable {
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100% !important;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0;
}
.aolReplacedBody p {
    margin:0 !important;
}
.pe-bullets p, .pe-sub-bullets p {
    margin: 0 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #333333 !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 100% !important;
}
table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link, .yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    background: none !important;
}
.im {
    color: black;
}
div[id="tablewrap"] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 740px!important;
}
div[id="tablewrap"] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 740px!important;
}
table[class="fulltable"], td[class="fulltd"] {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
.ExternalClass * {
    line-height: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td {
    line-height: 100%;
}
.ecxoutlookcom {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.ecxoutlookcomsocial {
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:4px;
}
.ecxwidthfix {
    width:100% !important;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.ecxdisc-bg {
    background:#ffffff !important;
}
.ecxlogo-marg {
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.ecxpe-headline p {
    padding-top:10px !important;
}
.ecxpe-btn {
    height:70px !important;
}
.ecxpe-ol {
    Padding-[(AlignDirection)]:20px !important;
    padding-bottom:0px !important;
    margin:0 !important;
}
.ExternalClass .ecxpe-across-image {
    padding-bottom:20px !important;
}
.ExternalClass .ecxpe-text p, .ExternalClass .ecxpe-id-details p {
    display:inline;
    line-height:200% !important;
}
.ExternalClass .ecxpe-subtitle p {
    display:inline;
    line-height:150% !important;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.ExternalClass .ecxpe-headline p {
    display:inline;
    line-height:120% !important;
}
.ExternalClass .ecxpe-headline {
    padding-bottom:20px !important;
}
.ExternalClass .ecxpe-subtitle {
    padding-top:10px !important;
}
.ecxpe-bullets p, .ecxpe-sub-bullets p, .ecxpe-ol p {
    display:inline !important;
}
table[class=pe-data-table] {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:none !important;
}
table[class=pe-data-table] tr {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
table[class=pe-data-table] tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
table[class=pe-data-table] td {
    border-bottom:0 !important;
}
a[href^=tel] {
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 620px), screen and (max-width: 620px) {
.pe-split-image-con {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
img[class=pe-across-image] {
    width:auto !important;
    max-width:100% !important;
}
table[class=pe-split-image-con] {
    background: none !important;
}
td[class=pe-split-image] {
    display:block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    float: right !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
td[class=pe-split-image] img {
    display:block !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    max-width: 333px !important;
}
td[id=pe-split-image-b] img {
    display:block !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    max-width: 333px !important;
}
table[id="backgroundTable"] {
    padding:0px!important;
}
td[class=btn-center-td] {
    text-align:center !important;
}
div[class=centering-btn], table[class=centering-btn] {
    width:100% !important;
}
table[class=btn-width] {
    text-align:center !important;
    width:100% !important;
}
table[class=pe-data-table-con] {
    width:100% !important;
}
table[class=pe-data-table] {
    width:100% !important;
}
table[class=pe-data-table] td {
    padding-left:10px !important;
    padding-right:10px !important;
    border-bottom:0 !important;
}
}
</style>
<!--Target Outlook 2007 and 2010-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
.pe-ol{Margin-[(AlignDirection)]:28px !important; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;}
.pe-ol td{border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd !important; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#dddddd; border-bottom-style:solid;}
.pe-bullets p, .pe-sub-bullets p{line-height:20px !important; margin-bottom:5px !important;}
.pe-subtitle p{margin-bottom:5px !important; }
.pe-image img{width:auto !important;  padding-bottom:20px !important; }
.pe-image{padding-bottom:15px !important;}
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--Target Outlook older than 2007 and 2010-->
<!--[if lte mso 9]>
<style>
#tablewrap{width:740px !important;}
.pe-ol{Margin-[(AlignDirection)]:28px !important; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;}
.pe-ol td{border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd !important; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#dddddd; border-bottom-style:solid;}
.pe-bullets p, .pe-sub-bullets p{line-height:20px !important;}
.pe-subtitle p{margin-bottom:5px !important; }
.pe-image img{width:auto !important; padding-bottom:10px !important;}
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

</head>

                <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="90%" style="margin:0 auto;  border-top:1px solid #cccccc; padding-top:25px;" dir="[(Direction)]" class="widthfix pe-main-con">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)];" class="pe-content">
  <!-- Begining of HTML content blocks -->  
  <!-- Data in Table  format -->                          
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="pe-data-table-con" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
  <tr>
    <td><table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" border-collapse:collapse; background-color:#f1f1f1;" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" dir="[(Direction)]" class="pe-data-table">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:bold;">1</td>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:normal;">########</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:bold;">2</td>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:normal;">#########</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:bold;">3</td>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:normal; ">#########</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:bold;">4</td>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:normal;">#########</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this guide to email styling](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Certain email clients have different formats and selectors that they allow (which is a pain). The `:nth-child(n)` pseudo-selector you're using to alternate the colors is only supported in iOS, Outlook.com, Apple Mail, and Gmail on Android (but not desktop).

I'd suggest putting the row styling inline, like this:

```
<tr style="text-align:[(RowColor)];">
    <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:bold;">3</td>
    <td valign="middle" style="text-align:[(AlignDirection)]; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd; font-weight:normal; ">#########</td>
</tr>
```